# Doesn't switch to another .jsp when I click submit. Spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

My controller. When I open the browser, the start page starts.jsp and create model User, which haves one field(String name) and set,get method. In start.jsp haves field of text and submit "LOGIN".

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView start() {
        return new ModelAndView("start", "user", new User());
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/input", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView input(@ModelAttribute("user") User user) {
        return new ModelAndView("input", "userName", user);
    }
}
```

My start page. Have text field and submit.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<html>
<head>
    <title>start</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>TEST</h1>

<form:form method="post" commandName="user" action="input">
    <input type="text" name="name"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="LOGIN">
</form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

My problem: I open localhost:8080/webapp and input name. In the moment there is creating examplar of model User. I push "LOGIN" and I turn in localhost:8080/input, where "input.jsp" is two page, which output "Hello world, {name}". But if I replace action="input" in start.jsp with action="webapp\input" then everything is good. But I think it's bad idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any issues with your code. I tried to set this example and works fine for below configuration.

webapp-servlet.xml:

```
<context:component-scan base-package = "com.test" />

   <bean class = "org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name = "prefix" value = "/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
      <property name = "suffix" value = ".jsp" />
   </bean>
```

JSP locations :

```
\WEB-INF\jsp\input.jsp
\WEB-INF\jsp\start.jsp
```

sample input.jsp:

```
<%@ page import="com.test.*" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>start</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>TEST</h1>
<%
    User user   = (User)request.getAttribute("userName");
%>
 Hello - <%=user.getName() %>
</body>
</html>
```

No changes required in `start.jsp` and `HomeController`